# 3V Current source with low voltage drop

Tags: analog, current-source, current-limiting, ldo

I'm trying to make a IR laser diode driver which needs 1.9V and ~80-100 mA constant current. Most of laser driver circuits in web has LM317 as a current source but that design has always voltage drop around 2.5V. Since I have 3V supply, i'm trying to find an alternative way with low drop-out voltage. 
I have found LT3085 ([Datasheet](https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3085fb.pdf)) which says 275mV dropout voltage.

[image: LM3085]

In datasheet's typical application section there is a circuit for Current Source but Vin=10V. Since LT3085 has "Wide Input Voltage Range 1.2V to 36V". How can I use with 3V supply?

Comment: By reading page 7 of the datasheet

Comment: Should work with Vin > 1.9V [vout] + 0.275V [dropout voltage] + 0.1 * 2 [volts across 2R]

Comment: @PlamsaHH or page 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that regulator has low drop out, *but* it requires a supply voltage for the internal circuitry (not for the load) thats a 1.5V more than the output voltage.  configure it as a current sink.

- connect the load between `+3V` and `in`
- connect `Vcontrol` to `+3V`
- connect `set` to `31K resistor` to `ground`
- connect `out` to `3.3 ohms resistor` to `ground`

Comment: Is there a equation to calculate different Iload values?

Comment: Ihe formula is something like r1/r2*10uA  (but I simulated it in ltspice which is a free download)